# Onclick event in J2ME

Tags: java, java-me

I am new to J2ME programming. I need on click event on choice group question.

I have one Choice group question to select gender either male or female.

if we select male, I need to generate new choice question in the same form.

Please share some code for "On Click" event for choice group questions.

Comment: put your code which you have tired

Answer (score 0):

in your "midlet" define this variables:

```
private Form frm = null;
private Command cmdSelect = null;
```

past this in your "midlet constractor":

```
this.frm = this.getForm();
Display.getDisplay(this).setCurrent(this.frm);
```

append this method in your midlet class:

```
private Form getForm()
{
    Form form = new Form("test");

    ChoiceGroup choice = new ChoiceGroup(null, ChoiceGroup.EXCLUSIVE);
    choice.append("Male", null);
    choice.append("Female", null);

    form.append(choice);
    this.cmdSelect = new Command("Select", Command.OK, 1);
    form.addCommand(this.cmdSelect);               

    form.setCommandListener(this);

    return form;
}
```

and paste this code in commandAction method for get index of choice:

```
int index = ((ChoiceGroup)this.frm.get(0)).getSelectedIndex();
```